# Performance Counter Input string was not in a correct format C#

Tags: c#, wmi

Here is my code

```
float cpuLoad = 0;

try{
    MessageBox.Show("Running");

    //CPU Load
    PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
    cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
    cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
    cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

    MessageBox.Show("Performance Counter Created");

    cpuLoad = cpuCounter.NextValue();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    cpuLoad = cpuCounter.NextValue();

    MessageBox.Show("Clock Speed Gathered");

    //Remaining Code
}
catch(Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
```

I have a try and catch around it and here is the exception it throws `Input string was not in a correct format`.

It gets through printing the first two Message Boxes, And then throws the exception.

Now here is what I cant get my head around, It works on Windows 7 Ultimate and Windows Server 2003, but on my colleagues Windows 7 Ultimate it Fails. It use to work on his computer, but suddenly its just stopped. The only difference in the near history has been that he has changed his Network.

**Edit**

Framework 4 was updated this morning. But I have it on my machine as well, so if it was the framework issue why is it not occurring on mine

Any ideas cause im lost

**Tested on his machine**

Its failing at the first `cpuLoad = cpuCounter.NextValue()`

**Stack Trace**

```
System.FormatException was unhandled
  Message="Input string was not in a correct format."
  Source="mscorlib"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
       at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetStringTable(Boolean isHelp)
       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_NameTable()
       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_CategoryTable()
       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CounterExists(String category, String counter, Boolean& categoryExists)
       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CounterExists(String machine, String category, String counter)
       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.Initialize()
       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.NextSample()
       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.NextValue()
       at CounterTest.Form1..ctor() in C:\Users\x\Documents\x\Applications & Software Development\C# Projects\CounterTest\CounterTest\Form1.cs:line 35
       at CounterTest.Program.Main() in C:\Users\x\Documents\x\Applications & Software Development\C# Projects\CounterTest\CounterTest\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Oh the application is being compiled in Debug Mode if that makes any difference

Comment: Could you post the stack trace please?

Comment: So, what call exactly throws the exception?

Comment: Not as of yet, The compiler is on my machine and im Remoting into his machine. Sorry i am a bit unfamiliar with stack trace

Comment: gencha - Im guessing `cpuCounter.NextValue();` is where there is a problem, but it works on every other machine ive tested

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you may find that this is an issue with the performance counters not working correctly. If you open perfmon (Start>Run>Perfmon) and see an error like this.

```
---------------------------
Performance Monitor Control
---------------------------
Unable to add these counters:

\Memory\Available MBytes
\Memory\% Committed Bytes In Use
\Memory\Cache Faults/sec
\Memory\Cache Faults/sec
\PhysicalDisk(*)\% Idle Time
\PhysicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk Queue Length
\Network Interface(*)\Bytes Total/sec
```

Then you will need to rebuild the counters from the PerfStringBackup.ini in the Windows\System32 folder. Follow this here for more info: http://drayblog.gotdns.com/index.php/2010/02/04/diagnostics-performancecounter-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format/.

Comment: Awesome. I had this problem on a totally unrelated commercial program that has no docs and support (nor source code), and could fix it with your post.

Comment: This link is not working anymore, so I recommend to use this link: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/yongrhee/2009/10/06/how-to-rebuild-performance-counters-on-windows-vistaserver20087server2008r2/

Comment: But this recommendation didn't help me, I've found another option: just run a command "lodctr /r" and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance the (spoken/written) language on your co-worker's machine is set differently than yours, or that they fiddled with any of the localization settings on that machine?  This is often a source of subtle bugs in .NET programs, especially when converting a string to/from different formats...

Comment: Highley unlikley. But even so if that was the case. Why would a. Version that i compiled on my machine, fail when i copy the binary over?